# What is the sum of the all possible $6$ digits numbers which are chosen in the set of {$0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$}

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, solution-verification, combinations

When i get around in park , i thought about combinatorics and made up a question in my mind.

However, i cannot be sure about my solution because as you know , it is very easy to miss some details in combinatorics.So , i want to be checked my solution here.

Question: What is the sum of the all possible $6$ digits numbers which are chosen in the set of {$0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$}

My humble attempt:

First step-) We can put $1$ element in the first digit in the set of {$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$},so there left $7+3=10$ possible numbers to put into the other $5$ digits. We can calculate it by $\frac{10 \times9\times8\times7\times6}{3!}=5040$ (we made division because of the zeros)

$\therefore 5040\times(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8=36)\times10^5$

Second Step-) We have chosen one element for the first digit which is not zero.Then, for the second digit:

$1\times(\frac{7\times9\times8\times7\times6}{3!}=3528)\times10^4$

This will continue up to the sixth digits in the same logic.

Then $5040\times10^5+3528\times10^4+3528\times10^3+3528\times10^2+3528\times10^1+3528\times10^0=543199608$

Is my solution correct ? If not, can you write the correct solution.

Moreover , even if it is corect if you know much shorter way, can you share with us ?

Have a nice day...

Comment: I don't know anything about combinatorics, as I'm a basic algebra person, but that effort was nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your approach to the question is correct, however, there seems to be one mistake. In your solution you claim that there are $\frac{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6}{3!} = 5040$ numbers with a particular starting digit. However, this is not quite correct. To illustrate your mistake here is a simpler example:

#### A simpler example

Let us say that we have the digits $\{0,0,1,2,3,4\}$ and we want to find all of the numbers of length 4 that start with $1$. Then we can list them all out to find that there are $33$ of them:

- $1234, 1243, 1324, 1342, 1423, 1432$
- $1023, 1024, 1032, 1034, 1042, 1043, 1203, 1204, 1230, 1240, 1302, 1304, 1320, 1340, 1402, 1403, 1420, 1430$
- $1002, 1003, 1004, 1020, 1030, 1040, 1200, 1300, 1400$

How the total number is calculated is perhaps hinted by the way I have arranged the numbers above. Namely, we want to calculate in how many ways we can get a number of length $4$ starting with $1$ such that none of the zeros are used, one of the zeros is used, or all of the zeros are used.

- If no zero gets used we get  $ \binom{3}{0} \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 6$ results.
- If one zero gets used we get $ \binom{3}{1} \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 18 $ results.
- If two zeros get used we get $ \binom{3}{2} \cdot 3 = 9$ results.

The sum of these yields exactly $33$. However, if I understood your calculation correctly, you would have claimed that there are $\frac{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}{2!} = 30$ results which is incorrect.

#### Back to the original problem

Now coming back to the original problem let us apply the same procedure. Consider any number $XZZZZZ$ where $X$ is fixed and each $Z$ represents an arbitrary digit.

- If no zero gets used we get  $ \binom{5}{0} \cdot \frac{7!}{2!}  = 2520 $ results.
- If one zero gets used we get $ \binom{5}{1} \cdot \frac{7!}{3!} = 4200$ results.
- If two zeros get used we get $ \binom{5}{2} \cdot \frac{7!}{4!} = 2100$ results.
- If three zeros get used we get $ \binom{5}{3} \cdot \frac{7!}{5!} =  420 $ results.

So in total there are $9240$ numbers where $X$ is the first digit.

Now note that an integer contributes nothing to the sum if it is $0$ and fix the first two digits so that our number is given by $XYZZZZ$. We then ask ourselves how many numbers of this kind we can make. This is simply a slight alteration of what we did before.

- If no zero gets used we get  $ \binom{4}{0} \cdot \frac{6!}{2!}  = 360 $ results.
- If one zero gets used we get $ \binom{4}{1} \cdot \frac{6!}{3!} = 480$ results.
- If two zeros get used we get $ \binom{4}{2} \cdot \frac{6!}{4!} = 180$ results.
- If three zeros get used we get $ \binom{4}{3} \cdot \frac{6!}{5!} =  24 $ results.

Now allowing $Y$ to be any non-zero value we see that there are $1044 \cdot 7  = 7308$ numbers which start with $X$ and have a non-zero second coefficient.

Since the same procedure can be applied to the number $XZZZZZ$ where any $Z$ is replaced by a $Y$, we conclude that our answer is:

$$36 \cdot \left( 9240 \cdot 10^5 + 7308 \cdot 11111 \right)$$

#### A general solution

By now, you might be able to see how we can construct the general solution to this problem. If we have an input of consisting of $m$ zeros, the first $n$ positive integers and you are creating a number of length $r$ with $m \leq r-2$ and $n \geq r$ then I believe the general solution to this problem is given by:

$$ \frac{(n)(n+1)}{2} \cdot  
\left( 
10^{r-1}\sum_{i=0}^m \left[\binom{r-1}{i} \cdot \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-r+i)!} \right] 
+ \left(\sum_{i=0}^{r-2} 10^i\right)
\sum_{i=0}^m\left[\binom{r-2}{i} \cdot \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-r+i)!} \right] 
\right)
$$

### Comment

Combinatorics is not my strong suit by any stretch of the imagination, so by all means, please point out anything you think is incorrect or is explained poorly.

Comment: Congrats on your first answer.

Comment: Welcome! In your conclusion, you wrote $7308 \cdot 1111$ which should have been $7308 \cdot 11111$. Correcting that yields $36,187,170,768$, which I confirmed with a bit of code.

Comment: @BenjaminWang Thank you kindly.

Comment: @DanielMathias Thank you for pointing out the typo. I have made the respective change.

Comment: @TorridGlacier thank you for this elegant answer :)