# Sum of the numbers whose digits are in $4-$ combinations of the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ with given restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

> Let $A$ be the set of all natural numbers whose digits are in the multiset $\{1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2\}$ (each digit can appear at most twice). Let $B$ be the set of all the $4$ digit numbers from $A$. Compute $\sum_{n\in B}n.$

Just in case, I found the generating function for the $4-$ combinations of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ with the given restriction and $|B|$:
$\begin{aligned}f(x)&=(1+x+x^2)^4\\&=\left(\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}\right)^4\\&=(1-x^3)^4(1-x)^{-4}=(1-4x^3+6x^6-4x^9+x^{12})\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-4}k(-x)^k\\&=(1-4x^3+6x^6-4x^9+x^{12})\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+3}kx^k\end{aligned}$

We need the coefficient $\langle x^4\rangle$ next to $x^4$:
$|B|=\langle x^4\rangle=\binom{4+3}4-4\binom{1+3}1=19.$

I don't think this helps, though.

I've seen a somewhat related [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1102364/942722) by Marc van Leeuwen and thought about imitating it, but I would either have to apply the following approach to every single $4$ permutation of$\{1,2,3,4\}$ with the given restriction or consider the sequence $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8)=(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4)$ and look at the first $4$ digits in each permutation, but I quit from the latter as I would overcount even more possibilities because some of the arrangements might appear in the other half of the each sequence I get.

In the linked answer, the number formed from a sequence obtained by a permutation of the initial sequence $(a_1,\ldots,a_6)$ is written in the form $$\sum_{i=0}^5a_{\sigma(i)}10^{i}$$ hence the sum is $$\sum_{\sigma\in S_6}\sum_{i=0}^5a_{\sigma(i)}10^i,$$ but repetitions lead to some numbers being counted as many times as is the product of factoriels of multiplicities od the digits, which is $12$, so the sum is rewriten as $$\sum_{i=0}^510^i\cdot\sum_{\sigma\in S_6}a_{\sigma(i)}=11111\sum_{\sigma\in S_6}a_{\sigma(i)}=12s$$ and  further $$\sum_{\sigma\in S_6}a_{\sigma(i)}=\sum_{k=1}^6a_{\color{red}{k}}\sum_{\sigma\in S_6}[\sigma(i)=\color{red}{k}]=\sum_{k=1}^6a_k\cdot\space |S_5|.$$
Then, it can easily be computed. However, I got lost in my task. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: If you can work out how many numbers start with $1$, call this $m$, then you can calculate $\sum_{n\in B}n$ as $(1+2+3+4) \times 1111 \times m$.

Comment: If you think there are $4^4-4-4\times3\times 4$ such numbers and their average value is $1111\times\frac{1+2+3+4}4$ then the calculation is not difficult

Comment: $(1+x+x^2)^4=x^8+4x^7+10x^6+16x^5+19x^4+16x^3+10x^2+4x+1$ so $13$ is not right.  But $19$ is not right either: clearly you have $4!=24$ cases when you just sort unique digits, and there are more when you use two the same.  Instead you want to expand $(w+x+y+z)^4$ and exclude cases of $w^3$ or $w^4$ or similar high exponents

Comment: @Henry, thank you! I will work that out, I've seen now that the expression I got for $\langle x^4\rangle$ yields $19$ instead of $13$ as I wrote, as well.

Comment: @Henry, so, you actually subtracted $4$ numbers with all equal digits and $\binom{4}3\cdot 4\cdot-$ for those with $3$ equal digits, which can be any of the $4$ given and the remaining $1$ is some of the other $3$? Silly me, I should've seen that in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these types of questions , you must use exponential generating functions instead of ordinary generating functions , because the order of numbers does matter.It is said that "each digit can appear at most twice" , so we can write the exponential generating function form of each digits such that $$\bigg(1+\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}\bigg)$$

*[About E.G.F](https://www.math.brown.edu/mchan2/2019Spring_2520/StudentPresentations/George_Exponential_Generating_Functions.pdf)*

There are $4$ distinct digits , so we must find the coefficient of $[x^4]$ in the expansion of $$\bigg(1+\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}\bigg)^4$$

and multiply $[x^4]$ by $4!$ , or just find the coefficient of $\frac{x^4}{4!}$.

If you want to find the number of digits of length $n$ , then find  the coefficient of $[x^n]$ in the expansion of $$\bigg(1+\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}\bigg)^4$$

and multiply $[x^n]$ by $n!$ , or just find the coefficient of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$

*[CALCULATION OF EXPANSION](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expanded+form+of+%281%2B+x+%2B+x%5E2+%2F+2%29%5E4)*

So , answer is $$4! \times \frac{17}{2} =204$$

According to link , the number of $5$ digits numbers consisting of the given set and obey the restriction is equal to $$5! \times 5 = 600$$

Do you get the idea ?

Now , It is time to find the summation. By using the logic of E.G.F . Lets find the number of digits of lenght $4$ and starting with $1$ :

- If it start with $1$ , then we must find the number of digits of lenght $3$ , it can be found by E.G.F such that $$3!\times [x^3]\bigg(1+\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}\bigg)^3 \bigg(1+\frac{x^1}{1!}\bigg)$$

*[CALCULATION OF EXPANSION](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expanded+form+of+%281%2B+x+%2B+x%5E2+%2F+2%29%5E3+%281%2Bx%29)*

So , it is $3! \times (17/2)=51$ , we can take it as $1000 \times 51 =51,000$ to find the summations .$51$ is also valid for when it start with $2$ , $3$ or $4$. Then ,

- For starting with $2$ : $2 \times 51 \times 1000=102,000$
- For starting with $3$ : $3 \times 51 \times 1000=163,000$
- For starting with $4$ : $4 \times 51 \times 1000=204,000$

Then , the summation of the digits of thousands is equal to $51,000+102,000+163,000+204,000 =520,000$

Can you calculate the rest ? You will just find for hundredss , tens and ones digits

I think you stuck in finding the number of possible digits , the rest is classical basic summation problem.

Comment: Bulbasaur, thank you for mentioning we use E.G.F.'s when the order matters, it was only after reading your answer that I finally noticed the note in my script. May I ask, did you multiply $\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}2\right)^3(1+x)$ by $3!$ because in the generating function, there is $3!$ in the denominator?

Comment: In that expression  , i firstly found the coefficient of $x^3$ in the expansion of multiplicaiton of exponential generating functions.After that , i multiply the coefficent of $x^3$ by $3!$. I could have reached the solution by just finding the coefficient of $x^3 / 3!$ in the expansion of exponential generating functions

Comment: @Autumn you are welcome , yeah thats why i multiply it by $3!$.

Comment: @Autumn to understand the logic of E.G.F , i recommend you a book such that "discrete math and application by Kenneth Rosen" . They are very beautiful explanation in that book for deep learning

Comment: So, after we sum thousands, we again investigate case by case for $3$ digit numbers starting with the same digit we considered for $1000$ or any of the remaining ones for hundreds and have subcases that divaricate? Since you invested your time, I want to invest mine to understand. (:

Comment: @Autumn sorry for late reply , it was so late in my country ,so i slept and could not answer. Anyway , yes , your thought is right ! ıt will dericate , i am putting a link here that may be guideline for you : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3956414/what-is-the-sum-of-the-all-possible-6-digits-numbers-which-are-chosen-in-the-s

Comment: @Autumn for more tricky way , remember probability.. what is the probability that $4$ digit numbers consisting of given set starts with $3$ ? The answer is $2/8 =1/4$ , so when you find all lenght of $4$ digit numbers satisfying your condition , $1/4$ of them will start with $3$. For example , we found that this is equal to $204$ , and $1/4$ of $204$ is equal to $51$. This is also valid for houndress , tens and ones. This was an another approach...